# Downloading nodejs from default repository during maven build

Tags: node.js, maven, maven-plugin

I have a problem with my maven build, more exactly with downloading the nodejs package.
It works when the package name is node-v16.16.0-linux-x64.tar.gz, it can find it in https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.16.0.
But sometimes it looks for the node-v16.16.0-linux-x64-**musl**.tar.gz package, then I get error 404, not found. I checked the package on the repository manually and it is true, it is not there.

The question is why it is looking for the node-v16.16.0-linux-x64-**musl**.tar.gz and whether I can set somehow the fix package name in pom.xml configuration except of the nodeVersion.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
          <execution>
              <id>install node and npm</id>
              <goals>
                  <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
            
                **<nodeVersion>v16.16.0</nodeVersion>
                <downloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</downloadRoot>
                **
            </configuration>
```

Thank you for any help
Anita

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and I found out that https://nodejs.org/dist/
works perfectly well for local running, but when you start building using docker then docker (at least the alpine version) uses version node-v16.16.0-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz and there are no versions with the suffix -musl.tar.gz in repo https://nodejs.org/dist/